# Call any Wordpress PHP function via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

It's very difficult for me to learn the basics of AJAX since I was managed to find only complicated examples. In fact, I want to do an apparently simple thing, but I wasn't able to find any easy solution. There are numerous instructions how to use AJAX to check various forms, etc. But there is few data how this technology work in WordPress.

The official instruction was useless to me as well:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

*What exactly I need?*

For example, I have some function in functions.php. Let it be a just simple string:

```
<?php 

function do_echo() {

echo "Hello";

}
```

Now, I want to create a button inside my post and call do_echo() using AJAX.

```
<button class="my_button" type="button" role="button">Click Me</button>
```

So, the first and foremost thing I want to do is just push on the button and get "Hello, world!" displayed.

Of course, in fact, I need to execute the more complicated function. But, first of all, I need to do these simple things.

I realize that I need to do something like this using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
url: '/path/to/file',
type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, 
or html)',
data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
console.log("complete");
});
```

I understand that I need to do something like this in PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_(action)', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)', 'my_action_callback');
```

But I can't understand what exact steps I need to do to attach these things to WordPress.

Can anyone assist me with the **simple** instruction how to call any PHP function from functions.php in **WordPress** using AJAX when the button was clicked?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, let's write simplified example for this.

Here is a sample for functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sayhello', 'say_hello_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_sayhello', 'say_hello_function');
function say_hello_function(){
echo 'hello';
exit();
}
```

And this is front-end part:

```
<button class="my_button" type="button" role="button">Click Me</button>

<script>
jQuery(".my_button").click(function(){

jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'sayhello'}, 
function (msg) { alert(msg);});

});

</script>
```

UPD:

To display returned data in your website content:

```
   <script>
    jQuery(".my_button").click(function(){  
    jQuery.get(ajaxurl,{'action': 'sayhello'}, 
    function (msg) { jQuery(".result_area").html(msg);});
    });
   </script>
```

To get above code working you need to have a div with "result_area" class.

```
<div class="result_area"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry... I start to realize )))

Comment: In the given example add_action() functions call say_hello_function; At the 1st row you see add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sayhello', 'say_hello_function'), right? add_action is WP Core function which executes second parameter as a function.

Comment: It can be interpreted so: add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sayhello', 'say_hello_function') =  Hey WP, run a function called 'say_hello_function' when you get action=sayhello  GET parameter from front-end side and return its output to front-end side.

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry. I was inattentive! You're right...

Comment: I know that I need to write something like die() at the end. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, "die" or "exit". i have written exit() in my example, check it please.

Comment: If exit() and die() are equal, this should work. Thank you for your assistance! Will this method work for any WordPress function from functions.php? If so, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, they are equal. About last question: Yes, of course, it will. "sayhello" and "say_hello_function" are the main keys in these example. Reproduce them how many you want, and all of them would work ok.

Comment: Elvin, but I still can't realize how can I print "Hello, world!" physically in HTML. For example, say_hello_function() gets a table from MySQL database, so I want to click the button and get this table physically appeared on my web page, not in console message. This exactly what I can't realize in the AJAX technology. Perhaps, it looks like a stupid question, but that's why I need AJAX (to show something on my page via button click without reloading this page).

Comment: It depends on where  you want to put it. Now i will update my answer and add an example for displaying returned data in the given DIV element.

Comment: Well, this works fine. Thanks for such an excellent explanation. But when I'm trying to retrieve something more complex, such as function say_hello_function(){
echo (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'show_name', true ));
exit(); I get nothing. If to remove "exit();" http://127.0.0.1:8080/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=sayhello returns "0," which means it doesn't work. I will continue to deal with this problem by myself. But if you can help me with this, I'll appreciate.

Comment: Zero is returned when 1. You forget to add add_action with nopriv. 2. You use wrong action name.

Answer (score 3):

The best pratice is using [WP Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

Wordpress provide an simple and organized way to add API Routes that return JSON.

You can register your routes in `function.php` or another loaded file.

Major WP files will be loaded and you can use your functions.

WP example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Grab latest post title by an author!
 */
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
  $posts = get_posts( array(
    "author" => $data["id"],
  ) );

  if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
    return null;
  }

  return $posts[0]->post_title;
}

add_action( "rest_api_init", function () {
  register_rest_route( "myplugin/v1", "/author/(?P<id>\d+)", array(
    "methods" => "GET",
    "callback" => "my_awesome_func",
  ) );
} );
```

Comment: Hello, Maxwell! Thank you for this hint. I will study WP Rest API. Maybe this will work for me.

Comment: If you like OO, check out the WP rest class to extend.